# upload Image to firebase storage and NOT File

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

There are lot of references of uploading a dart:io 'File' but I want to upload a material.dart Image to firebase.

My Image comes from a processed Thumbnail of a video and not just picked by a Image picker.

This is how I generate a thumbnail,

```
Future<ThumbnailResult> genThumbnail(url) async {
    //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Uint8List bytes;
    final Completer<ThumbnailResult> completer = Completer();
      bytes = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
          video: url,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          maxHeight: 250,
          maxWidth: 300,
          timeMs: 0,
          quality: 0);

    int _imageDataSize = bytes.length;
    print("image size: $_imageDataSize");

    final _image = Image.memory(bytes);
    //final _file =File.fromRawPath(bytes);

    _image.image
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(ThumbnailResult(
        image: _image,
        dataSize: _imageDataSize,
        height: info.image.height,
        width: info.image.width,
      ));
    }));
    return completer.future;
  }
```

and this is how File is uploaded to firebase

```
String Thumbfileurl = await uploadFile(thumbResult.image, fileName, fileType);
```

And inside uploadFile()

```
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);
```

So as you see , A File is needed , but i have an Image , is there a way to Convert Image to File or is there any workaround to achieve this .

Comment: you have `bytes` - those "bytes" are encoded image like png, jpg, webp etc - in your case it is jpg as you use `ImageFormat.JPEG`

Comment: I think you need to impress your image before uploading it to firebase storage.
You need to import image.dart file (a built-in package in flutter)  which provides us with the function to encode our image